# Ĉu la kreantoj de la Esperanta kurso en Duolingo estas famaj Esperantistoj?

Tags: duolingo

Duolingo certe helpis multe da homoj trovi kaj lerni Esperanton facile kaj amuze. Mi pensas, ke ĝi estas bonega ideo.

Mi scivolis, ĉu ĝiaj kreantoj estas konataj kiel instruistoj ie (ekz. *lernu!* aŭ iu lernejo), aŭ ĉu ili kreis iajn aliajn bonajn ilojn. Bedaŭrinde, mi ne povas trovi iliajn nomojn.

Mi pensis, ke eble ili ankaŭ estas tie ĉi en StackExchange!

Comment: A new tag proposal, too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Por scii pli pri la kreantoj de la Duolinga kurso, vi povas iri al la ["Incubator"-paĝo](https://incubator.duolingo.com/courses/eo/en/status) de tiu kurso. En ĝi estas nuntempe listigataj 10 kunlaborantoj (sed multe pli kunlaboris por tiu kurso). Vi povas klaki sur la profilbildon de iu por aliri al profilo-paĝo de tiu. Tie vi povos trovi kelkajn informojn pri tiu kunlaboranto.

Do ekzemple, se vi klakas sur la profilbildon de amuzulo/Chuck Smith, vi povos legi:

> Founder/CEO of Ludisto, designer of iPad board game What the Shell

De tiuj informoj, vi povos dedukti ĉu la persono estas fama aŭ ne. La respondo al tio dependas al kiu vi demandas. Laŭ mi kaj miaj nurpartaj konoj de Esperantujo, la plej famaj estas *Chuck Smith* (li fondis la Esperantan Vikipedion), *Anna Lowenstein* (ŝi estas fama nuntempa verkisto kaj membro de la Akademio) kaj *Yves Nevelsteen* (kiu estras la vortdeponejon Komputeko). Se vi demandas al la poliglota komunumo, ili respondos al vi *Judith Meyer*.

Sed nun, ili estas ĉiuj famaj, ankaŭ pro la Duolinga kurso.

Answer (score 2):

Chuck Smith estas fama. Jen tiu: http://i0.wp.com/www.lindsaydoeslanguages.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/Lindsay-Dow-Chuck-Smith-Polyglot-Gathering-Berlin-Esperanto-Magazine.jpg

Kaj tiu: https://eo.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chuck_Smith

Sed mi scias pri la aliaj.

Answer (score 1):

Ĉiu esperantisto estas fama.

http://bulteno.esperanto-usa.org/2015/3/20-nask.html

> Kiam ni babilis kun Nazaré, ni ridis, ĉar ŝi ofte uzis la vorton “fama”. Ŝajne ĉiuj ŝiaj esperantistaj amikoj kaj konatoj estas “famaj” laŭ ŝi — eĉ ni!